# How to copy Power BI Analysis to Word

Tags: powerbi

I am using Power BI desktop to analyse data

I built a graph and from this graph I right clicked then got to "Analyze" option then choose "Find where the distribution is different"

So far everything is ok

I get the analysis I want

[image]

But when I try to copy the text, i found it is uncopyable.

how can I copy the analysis text and charts to word document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Power BI` desktop doesn’t it support currently, but you can export the report through `PowerPoint` format (publish the report to `Power BI Service` and select File->Export to `PowerPoint`).

Another option is to make a screenshot of the report and insert it into `Word` document. See discussion [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Copying-a-Visual-from-Power-BI-to-MS-Word-MS-Power-Point/td-p/412790)